# I want to submit a form but after i have checked some values

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I want to submit a form but after i have checked some values match before i continue. ideally i want before submission for the code to check that id Total equals id: Approve and Not, at the moment this does nothing

```
<form id="sheet" method="post" action=".application.php" >
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <label>Total</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id = " Total" name="Total" type="text" size="20" />
    </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
    <td>
        <label>Approved :</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="Approved" name="Approved" type="text" size="20" />
     </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>
        <label>Not Approved:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="Not" class="control" name="NotApproved" type="text"    size="20" />
    </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
<button id="submit"  name="submit" type="submit"   onclick="Checker();">POST</button>
</form>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $('form').submit(function() {

    if ($('#Total').val() !==  $('#Approved').val() + $('#Not').val()) {
    alert('check your values');
      return false;  
    }else{
        return true;
    }

    });
 });
```

Comment: use preventdefault to prevent the form from submitting. Then check if everything is OK, and submit the form. Also make sure to check server side as well, is somebody disables his/her javascript, your script wont work anymore.

Comment: In your if statement you are trying to add strings together. ie Approved and Not are strings not numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert values to "numbers", you are currently comparing `string` to `string`+`string`.

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6f46ks5h/).

```
var total = Number( $("#total").val() ),
    approved = Number( $("#Approved").val() ),
    notApproved = Number( $("#Not").val() );

if ( total !== (approved + notApproved) ) {
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another problem with your code is that you are using this:

```
$('form').submit(...);
```

You are selecting all forms in the dom, so the same validation will be apply to all submitted forms if there are others.

Maybe you want to select your form by id, in your case would be something like:

```
$('#sheet').submit();
```

An example of how to sumit a form after check validation using your code would be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sheet').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var total = Number ($("#Total").val()),
            approved = Number ($("#Approved").val()),
            notApproved = Number ($("#Not").val());
        if(total != (approved + notApproved)){
          return false;
        }else{
          return true;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It's not an answer to the question. Its more a comment :)

Comment: Sorry for that, I've updated the answer providing a real answer